# Failed to connect to mLab by mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to connect to mLab on my terminal when I followed the instruction on the website
This is the command that I typed

`mongo ds151461.mlab.com:51461/simplelogin -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>`

This is the result I got:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://ds151461.mlab.com:51461/simplelogin
MongoDB server version: 3.2.13
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
2017-06-12T19:12:35.498-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1459:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

Btw, when I run the local mongoDB, I use mongod to make it work and mongo does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests you have an authentication error. 
Which is possibly happening because you are using credentials of a user that is not valid for the database "simplelogin".
(You can't use mlab credentials here, I made this mistake, might help someone, so worth a mention.)

If you don't have a user in the database yet. Follow following steps to create a user.

1 - Go to your database page, by clicking on the database from the landing page. 
    Or use following url, https://mlab.com/databases/simplelogin (you have to be logged in for this to work)

2 - From there click the "Users" tab. Click on the button that says "Add database user", and enter username and password (lets say username - "myuser" and password - "mypassword" for this illustration). Click the "Create" button.

3 - Use those credentials to connect to your database.

```
mongo ds151461.mlab.com:51461/simplelogin -u myuser -p mypassword
```

And it should work.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is the first time I use mLab, it works with your instruction